# UIView animations - When does it animate certain properties like scale and position?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I'm currently working with a UITableViewController which contains some UITableViewCells subclasses.

When layoutSubviews is called on these UITableViewCells, I change some of the cells' subviews' scales and positions depending on the width and height of the contentView. (The UITableViewCells have some subviews, and I change their scales and positions)

A good example is toggling edit mode, since it shortens the contentView by a bit.

When I do this, the scales and positions of my UITableViewCell's subview do animate

```
func toggleEdit() {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.35)

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.editing = !self.tableView.editing
    self.tableView.endUpdates()

    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

When I do this, ONLY the positions animate, the scales change immediately which looks really ugly:

```
func toggleEdit() {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.35)
    self.tableView.editing = !self.tableView.editing
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

I kind of found this out by accident, so I'm wondering now what kind of magic begin/end tableViewUpdate does, and how I can control myself in any scenario which properties should animate and which shouldn't.

Comment: Does the behavior persist if you use `setEditing:animated:` instead? Can you post your `layoutSubviews` code? Also, see the UIView docs for a list of which properties are animatable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That works. Thank you. But I'm wondering why this is needed to make them animate, why is it not enough to begin/commit animations. What does Apple's code underneath do different than me?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/endUpdates) state

> When you call endUpdates, UITableView animates the operations simultaneously

You could try changing things that you don't want animated in a `performWithoutAnimation(_:)` block

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
  // things you don't want to animate  
}
```

Comment: But I want them to animate. I do not want them to not animate. I want to find out what I can do to make certain things animated. In my case, the sclae did no animate, but I wanted it to.